# Dependency management with Heroku Java web apps

Tags: java, maven, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to web apps, the play framework, heroku and dependency management.

I've created a new Heroku Play framework based Java web app and I'm trying to install the dependencies for auth0 (https://addons.heroku.com/auth0#dev).

The auth0 documentation (https://docs.auth0.com/#!/web/java) only documents how to add a dependency with Maven.

There is no "pom.xml" file within the Heroku app files as I think is normally the case with Maven in a Java app. What *really* confuses me, is that in some areas on the Heroku documentation, it states that Maven is used by default for Java web apps, in other areas SBT, then within the project files there is a dependencies.yml file (under the conf directory).

I'm really confused as to how dependencies in Heroku Play Java web apps are managed (if its Maven by default then where's the pom.xml file?) and how I add the dependencies for auth0 and some other .Jar files (like JSOUP). There is very little documentation or examples on the dependencies.yml file, whether it's supposed to replace/supplement something like Maven or SBT, or how to add to it.

Does anyone know what the deal is with dependency management in Heroku?

Comment: As `sbt` is used to build Play-based applications you can just add `libraryDependencies += "com.auth0" % "auth0-servlet" % "1.4"` to your `build.sbt` file in your project and then you will get the dependency

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTDependencies

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.

Just to clarify a bit, I understand creating a new Play application includes dependency management with SBT.

What I don't understand is when you create a new Play application through *Heroku* it doesn't appear to include any dependency management. In the documentation it states dependency management is done with Maven by default, but there is no "pom.xml" file.

This image shows the file structure of a new Play Java app created on Heroku:
http://i.imgur.com/TaVnb7e.png

Comment: There is no SBT or Maven dependency setup there. But there is a dependencies.yml file. I don't understand why the documentation states it uses Maven, but then doesn't appear to:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#declare-dependencies-in-pom-xml

But instead there is a dependencies.yml file, which isn't really that well documented. Can anyone clarify how to either add dependency management to a *Heroku* play application or how to use the dependencies.yml file?

Comment: Maybe you are just reading the wrong part of the documentation. If you look [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-play#declare-dependencies) you will find a short explanation about the dependencies of a **Play** application (not Java).